# Install Craft 3 on Web Server

Tags: craft3, install, hosting

I scoured the the web to the ends of earth and couldn't find any info on how to install Craft 3 on my VPS. The package I downloaded is unconventional in many ways. Any ideas how to get Craft running?

By the way, why can't Craft 3 be installed like Wordpress?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a tutorial on setting up your first Craft CMS 3 project. I'm a little sad that it didn't come up in any Google searches :(

[Setting up a New Craft CMS 3 Project](https://nystudio107.com/blog/setting-up-a-craft-cms-3-project)

Comment: great tutorial. Just I had a few issues here. I've already installed Craft 2.0 version on my localhost server and I can't access the new craft 3 site on my server. It's a bit strange it doesn't work like WordPress. :(

Answer (score 4):

While Craft 3 is still in beta, the only way to install it is via Composer. If you’re unfamiliar with Composer, it’s a package manager (like npm) that attempts to make installing and updating PHP libraries easy via terminal commands.

Here's an abbreviated form of the steps found in the Craft docs on [installing Craft 3](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/installation.md#1-install-composer):

1. Download Composer on your VPS ([instructions here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx))
2. Create a new Craft project - `composer create-project -s RC craftcms/craft PATH`
3. Ensure the web server is pointing to the right directory and that your database is setup.
4. Point your browser to `http://website-url.com/index.php?p=admin` to complete the setup process.
5. With that, you should be running the latest RC of Craft!

I'd recommend checking out the [Craft 3 docs](https://github.com/craftcms/docs) and also Ryan Irelan's fantastic videos on [Installing Composer](https://mijingo.com/lessons/installing-composer-craft-cms/) and [Installing Craft 3](https://mijingo.com/lessons/installing-craft-cms-3/). If you have any more questions about the process, don't hesitate to ping me in the comments or post a message in the Craft CMS Slack group.

UPDATE: Pixel & Tonic has mentioned they're hoping to include a .zip download (similar to the Craft 2 installation process) when they fully release Craft 3 on April 4th. Till then, Composer is the only way to download & setup Craft 3.

Answer (score 1):

The Craft 3 docs are still abit rough around the edges if you are starting out with craft they can seem abit intimidating. Anyway the best place for you to start is here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5PxBmx74V8&t=125s. Its a tutorial by Ryan from Mijingo - Crafts official training partner. Seems like the best place to start :).

Answer (score 1):

yea, craft is little bit tricky when it comes to installation. As craft 3 is based on yii 2.0 [installation of yii 2.0 and craft is similar]. if you have previous experience in working with yii 2 then it should not be problem. Any Way lets make this easier for you.

Lets follow this

1. Install Composer on your server
2. then Run composer create-project -s RC craftcms/craft PATH[your web root path] for creating craft 3 project
3. then edit web server configuration file i.e httpd.conf for apache or nginx.conf file for nginx [this totally depends on your server configuration] change the document root and directory path to craft's web folder. save and restart web server.
4. Now go to your domain/admin and you should see craft 3 installation page.
5. Also Craft 3 doesnot have default template to display anything so you need to create one after you finish your installation so that it will display something when you open your primary domain.